# qt creator output give QOpenGLShaderProgram error in x86 Android emulator

Tags: android, qt-creator, qt5.7, x86-emulation

I have an Android program written QT/QML , When I deploy app to Arm Android Emulator , it works. But If I Deploy app to x86 Andorid Emulator, program is work but , Screen is white . There is no component to display. Application output is :

> .... QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program
>   is not linked W/libArizaMobil.so( 2651): (null):0 ((null)):
>   QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not
>   linked W/libArizaMobil.so( 2651): (null):0 ((null)):
>   QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program
>   is not linked W/libArizaMobil.so( 2651): (null):0 ((null)):
>   QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( dpr ): shader program is not
>   linked ......

Comment: You don't check error in linking I suppose? Do that.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen , Program works but there is no element to touch. Only white screen. When I touch screan , Warning above is appear.

Comment: But when you load the shader and link it, do you check for success?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes it is success . But there is no visial on screen